# Selenium VBA : driver.captureEntirePageScreenshot.Copy

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, screenshot

New to the forums, and new to Selenium VBA. Apologies in advance for my ignorance.
However I have searched for any VBA version of this that captures the full page element without plug-ins or use of Java.

I want to keep this as simple as possible to capture a full page screenshot then paste that from clipboard into sheets within excel.

Code I have so far I understand it can be improved and some of it may be unnecessary but I can't tell why it won't work when `bot.TakeScreenshot.Copy` does work but only captures the visible screen.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim bot As New WebDriver, rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2"), 
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown))

'this loops through each href in cells navigating to the page unless the cell has end in it

For Each cell In rng
TextBox2.Text = ActiveCell.Text
TextBox3.Text = ActiveCell(1, 2).Text
If ActiveCell.Text = "End" Then
bot.Quit
Else
bot.Start "chrome", TextBox2.Text
bot.Window.Maximize
bot.Get "/"

'this takes a screenshot of each url in the loop and copys it

bot.captureEntirePageScreenshot.Copy

'bot.TakeScreenshot.Copy

'this creates a new sheet names it according the relavent test related to the url and pastes it in that newlt created sheet

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = ActiveCell(1, 2).Text
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial

'this goes back to the original sheet to continue with loop

Worksheets("sheet1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

bot.Quit
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That is limitation of the driver and you can't do much about it

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani any resolution proposed for VBA? I'v seen Java alternate options.

Comment: Point me to the Java alternative ones

Comment: @TarunLalwani one of the chrome java but have no idea how to integrate ashot into VBA - https://www.quora.com/Can-we-take-full-page-screenshot-on-chrome-using-selenium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the headless browser

this is taken from the example code that comes with selenium

on win7 machine ... C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\Examples\VBScript

```
Option Explicit

Sub demoPhantomJSDriver()

    Dim aaa As Selenium.PhantomJSDriver
    Set aaa = New Selenium.PhantomJSDriver
    aaa.Get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba?sort=newest&pageSize=50"
    aaa.Window.Maximize

    Dim bbb As Object
    Set bbb = aaa.TakeScreenshot
    bbb.ToExcel Range("h3")
    Set bbb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer from @jsotola, I found you do not need to have the headless browser to do this.

```
Option Explicit
Public myChrome as Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub TakeScreenshot_Of_Page()
  Set myChrome = New Selenium.ChromeDriver 
  
  Dim URL as String
  URL="Https://YourSiteHere.com"
  
  myChrome.Start
  myChrome.Get URL
  
  MyChrome.TakeScreenshot.copy

End Sub
```

Additionally, you can take a screenshot of just one object if you ever needed this:

```
'Uses same declaration as snip above

Sub TakeScreenshot_Of_Object(ByVal XPath_STR as String)
  'Assumes you are already on "YourSiteHere.com" from previous routine
  Dim FindBy as new Selenium.By
  If myChrome.IsElementPresent(FindBy.XPath("""" & XPath_STR & """") Then
    myChrome.FindElementByXpath("""" & XPath_STR & """").TakeScreenshot.Copy
    'Now Do what you want with that given element from the Xpath provided.
  End If
End Sub
```